# Show number of executors and executor memory

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am runing a pyspark job using the command

`spark-submit ./exp-1.py --num-executors 8 --executor-memory 4G`

Is there a way to confirm that these configurations are getting reflected in during execution ?

Comment: did you try the spark web ui?

Comment: Thanks, got the information in spark web UI. but it shows the memory is almost half of what I am allocating per executor.

Answer (score 0):

There is a command `verbose` for checking configuration when spark job runs.

```
spark-submit --verbose ./exp-1.py --num-executors 8 --executor-memory 4G
```